# Add new classifier to existing tensorflow models

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I want to customize existing tensorflow object detection model ssd mobilenetv2 to solve multitask problem. How i can get copy output tensors in feature extractor and use it for my own classifier input layers.

Comment: Highly depends on what exact model you want to use, how is the checkpoint saved etc. If it is a frozen model you can't do it. If it is just a training snapshot you can simply copy all variables (weights and biases) from there and fine tune the layers you append. Anyway, the correct answer to your question would be: we can't tell, you need to provide a lot more details and what did you try so far.

Comment: @carobnodrvo [link](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29.tar.gz) i'll try to use this model.

Comment: @carobnodrvo i want use outputs of mobilenet v2 and redirect copy of it to my layers. i want to add text recognition of input image